# Calculate percentiles if we have probability density function data as x and y

Tags: python, probability, distribution, percentile, kernel-density

I have data extracted from a pdf graph where x represents incubation times and y is the density in a csv file. I would like to calculate the percentiles, such as 95%. I'm a bit confused, should I calculate the percentile using the x values only, i.e., using `np.precentile(x, 0.95)`?

data in plot: 
[image]

Comment: You want percentiles for x & y values ? Or you want to annotate it in the plot ?

Comment: @Zeek I want the precentile of x, but shouldn't I consider the pdf (y values) ?

Comment: Percentiles are based on the pdf values.  the 95th percentile is that x-value which has 95% of the area under the pdf to the left of it (or 5% to the right).  In calculus terms, the integral from -infinity to x is 0.95.

Comment: @pjs, thank you for your answer, so how can I calculate it? when I have 2 dimensinal arrays with both pdf and its corresponding x-value. Shouldn't  np.precentile(x, 0.95) give me the right value ?

Comment: @sakurami Not being a pythonista, I have no idea.  That's why I put the info relevant to your comment in a comment rather than attempt an answer.

Comment: @pjs, thank you for the info. and sorry for that

Comment: @sakurami I saw this through the `distribution` tag.  Not a problem, that's an appropriate tag and I found your question interesting.  There's certainly no need to apologize!

Comment: After poking around a bit, it looks like [numpy.trapz](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) may be what you want.

Comment: Suppose you have the 2-D array as `arr` and have the `x` values as the 2nd 1-D array inside. You could do something like this to get the percentile. `np.percentile(arr[1] , 0.95)`. Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you @pjs, I did not get the idea of trapz actually and how it can be used for percentile calculation

Comment: Thank you @Zeek, this exactly what I used for now, I have read couple of resources and they said I need to sort the observations and then calclate the presentile by multiplay n(size)* percentile and based on that I get the value of percentile of x. However, I saw also some use mean and standard deviation and I was wondering if the np.percentile() function is enough or should I use another way

Comment: @sakurami that depends on your use case, i.e. your endgame for all of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code which uses np.trapz (as proposed by @pjs). We take x and y arrays, assume it is PDF so first we normalize it to 1, an then start searching backward till we hit 0.95 point.
I've made up some multi-peak function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000

x = np.linspace(0.0, 6.0*np.pi, N)
y = np.sin(x/2.0)/x # construct some multi-peak function
y[0] = y[1]
y = np.abs(y)

plt.plot(x, y, 'r.')
plt.show()

# normalization
norm = np.trapz(y, x)
print(norm)

y = y/norm
print(np.trapz(y, x)) # after normalization

# now compute integral cutting right limit down by one
# with each iteration, stop as soon as we hit 0.95
for k in range(0, N):
    if k == 0:
        xx = x
        yy = y
    else:
        xx = x[0:-k]
        yy = y[0:-k]
    v = np.trapz(yy, xx)
    print(f"Integral {k} from {xx[0]} to {xx[-1]} is equal to {v}")
    if v <= 0.95:
        break
```

Comment: Hello @Severin Pappadeux, Many thanks for code, I run the code and compare it with the result of np.percentile both gave me the same results.

Comment: @sakurami If you have alternative version with np.percentile, please publish it as another answer, and I'll endorse it - it will definitely benefit people looking for answers.

Comment: @sakurami You could even pick Y as function of x from my code if you don't want to share actual data

Answer (score 0):

I have test both @Severin Pappadeux method and np.percentile and bith gave me the same result for 95 percentile

Here code of @Severin Pappadeux but with the data I used:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [ 5.  ,  5.55,  6.1 ,  6.65,  7.2 ,  7.75,  8.3 ,  8.85,  9.4 ,
      9.95, 10.5 , 11.05, 11.6 , 12.15, 12.7 , 13.25, 13.8 , 14.35,
      14.9 , 15.45, 16.  ]
y = [0.03234577, 0.03401444, 0.03559847, 0.03719304, 0.03890566,
     0.04084201, 0.04309067, 0.04570878, 0.04871024, 0.05205822,
     0.05566298, 0.05938525, 0.06304516, 0.06643575, 0.06933978,
     0.07154828, 0.07287886, 0.07319211, 0.0724044 , 0.0704957 ,
     0.0675117 ] 

N = len(x)

y[0] = y[1]
y = np.abs(y)

plt.plot(x, y, 'r.')
plt.show()

# normalization
norm = np.trapz(y, x)
print(norm)

y = y/norm
print(np.trapz(y, x)) # after normalization

# now compute integral cutting right limit down by one
# with each iteration, stop as soon as we hit 0.95
for k in range(0, N):
    if k == 0:
       xx = x
       yy = y
    else:
       xx = x[0:-k]
       yy = y[0:-k]
     v = np.trapz(yy, xx)
print(f"Integral {k} from {xx[0]} to {xx[-1]} is equal to {v}")

    if v <= 0.95:
       break

# Outputs = 
# 0.6057000785
# 1.0 
# Integral 0 from 5.0 to 16.0 is equal to 1.0
# Integral 1 from 5.0 to 15.45 is equal to 0.9373418687777172
```

and when I used **np.percentile()** on x as @Zeek suggests:

```
np.percentile(x, 95)
# Output= 15.45
```

So, both methods gave me **15.45** as the **95 percentile** of **x**